# i cant count the full list bot discord python

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the entire embed list but it always shows me the same number...

[image]

should appear

1
2
3
4
...

I don't know how to solve this problem

this is the code

```
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx):
    response = requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-leaderboards/hhes/visited-rooms/daily/latest.json")
    data = response.json()
    count=0
    for i in data:
        count=count+1
        
        content = f'\n\n{contar} - '.join(item['name'] for item in data)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You may need to learn more python, read more tutorials before continuing. You're not understanding at all the code you use actually : `item['name'] for item in data` iterate over ALL results, and you're doing it in a loop that iterate over ALL results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I just removed the .join() function and created the appending with a loop instead.

```
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx):
    response = requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-leaderboards/hhes/visited-rooms/daily/latest.json")
    data = response.json()
    
    count = 0
    content = ""

    for item in data:
        count = count + 1
        item = item["name"]
        content = content + f"\n{count} - {item}\n"

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```